# Regex (need to match 2 strings) - but also take into account characters

Tags: regex

In the web app a user submits a description. This description gets passed into a stored procedure that saves it to the db. While saving it runs a function on @Desc:

select @Desc=dbo.Replace('\b' + Abbrev + '\b',@Desc,ReplacementText,0) from TextDictionary

So it basically goes through all Abbrevs and if there is a match in '@Desc' it replaces it with the Abbreev's ReplacementText. Btw the Replace function is using SQLCLR to use C# regex.replace function.

The main problem is that some of their Abbreviations are 'MA', 'MA.', 'MA,', 'MA;', etc. To account for when they use an abbreviation in a description and there is a special character after it. This causes major problems because for example 'MA.' goes into my function and uses the . as a wildcard value. i.e. '\b' + MA. + '\b' So if there is text in the description such as MAS it will replace it with the 'MA.' replacement TEXT.

Comment: unclear for me. Did you want two patterns?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Can you show your comparison code?

Comment: `TE.ST is equal to TE.ST or TEST. is equal to TEST.` they are equal. what do you want to ask? you want to make punctuation into the matching?

Comment: I added to it. Sorry about not being descriptive enough.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood the problem, so bear with me if I'm not hitting it. As far as I understand, you want abbreviation to match for example MA when MA is alone, but also when MA is followed by a semi-colon. In this case you can make the semi-colon optional: for example something like `\bMA;?\b`

Comment: spider, this is exactly what I need. How would I account for multiple characters and is there anyway to account for all characters or am I going to have to request a list that the client will be using? I am assuming to account for multiple I would do ;?.?>?-?

Comment: you can list them in `[]`. For example, to make optional the character you listed: `[;>\-\.]?` should work. In your case it becomes `MA[;>.\-]?`. Note that you have to escape the hyphen `\-` because in the square brackets has a special meaning

Answer (score 0):

why you want use a regex for comparing two strings? if you want these 2 strings are  exactly the same as?.
where ever.
Maybe you need have 2 regular expresions. 
or do a count characters after the test regular expresions...

maybe an algorithm could be:

```
rg1 and rg2
str1 and str2
if ( test rg1 match with str1 and str2 )
  then equals = count_characters( rg1 ) and count_characters ( rg2 )
else ( test rg2 match with str1 and str2 )
  then equals = count_characters( rg1 ) and count_characters ( rg2 )
```

review your regular expresion, cause \b take into account white spaces and points too, maybe you should replace the end **\b** with a **\s** or **\s\b**

Comment: sorry is there a chance you can re-read my post. I don't think I was explaining it correctly.